# How to force re-render a React component from within another component?

Tags: reactjs

Disclaimer, I'm new to React so forgive me if I ask an obvious question.

My goal is to force re-render a component from a function (as opposed to doing it from [inside the component](https://davidwalsh.name/react-force-render)).

My component looks like this:

```
class LibraryClasses extends React.Component<ILibraryClassesProps> {

  public render() {

    const { classes } = this.props;

    // ... stuff ...

  }

}
```

In another component, I want to trigger a rerender event of this component. I can include it like this: `import LibraryClasses from '../libraryClasses/LibraryClasses';` but I don't understand how to initiate a re-render. I was hoping to do something like `LibraryClasses.forceUpdate();`

Thanks all :-)

Comment: Why do you want it to re-render? Because a prop or something in the state has changed? Then React should do that automatically.  If nothing has changed, then why re-render?

Comment: Aha, thanks for the quick response (I've updated the question accordingly) do I understand correctly that if `this.props` changes, the component should rerender?

Comment: If state or props change, the component will automatically re-render. This is why directly mutating either is forbidden, so that react can detect when a re-render is required. You should pretty much never need to force a re-render.

Comment: Aha, I see, that's very helpful, thanks